# Why is ask question search performing better than site search

Tags: discussion, support

When I'm about to ask a question, I search SO first to see if there are any related questions by entering my question title into the search box. Generally it finds unrelated questions. Then when I click 'ask question' and type in my title for the question, it finds questions more related to my question. Why are the two different. 'Ask question' filter seems to be much more accurate.

Comment: Not answering the specific question, but: generally I search google with "site:stackoverflow.com" instead of using the internal search-boxes. It's... better. =)